# Reload entity from DbEntityEntry after SaveChanges with eager loading

Tags: performance, entity-framework, caching, eager-loading

Background: Using EntityFramework 6 I'm creating a repository that holds in memory all its entities, for a performance reason, so I need after SaveChange update my "repository cache"

```
public class Person
{
    public decimal Incomes{get; set;}
    public Dependent Related {get; set;} 
}
public class Dependent
{
   ...
}
```

here is how I load into memory static field

```
var x= _set.Include(d => d.Related)
                .ToList();
            _memCache.AddRange(x);
```

Before SaveChanges I keep info of ChangeTrack

```
private void BeforeCommit(DbChangeTracker tracker)
    {
        foreach (var track in tracker.Entries<Person>())
        {
            switch (track.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    _toAdd.Add(track);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    _toDelete.Add(track.Entity.Id);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    _toModify.Add(track);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the problem when I'm processing new entities after reloading the DbEntityEntry the "Related" property of track.Entity is null because I can't  find a way to specify an Include(m=>m.Related) style

```
foreach (var track in _toAdd)
{
    await track.ReloadAsync();
    _memCache.Add(track.Entity);
}
```

Comment: After saving changes, your context should represent the database state of your entities. Why reload? By the way, doesn't necessarily help performance to stuff a context with a load of objects.

Comment: Of course but I haven't primary key value to find the entity in the context, and update de memCache Member

Comment: EF will write generated PK values into new entities right after saving them.

Comment: How about explicit loading it after reloading the entity, e.g. `await track.Reference(e => e.Related).LoadAsync();`

Comment: arnold EF do it in context but not in track i have check track.Entity and doesn't containt the updated values

Comment: We evidently lack some info to see how EF should behave here, but anyway, I wouldn't go this path. A bloated context can hardly be helpful in optimizing performance. Look for other caching strategies.

Comment: Ivan Stoev your solution maybe is not optimum but work me, becuase add, delete, or update isn't my more frequently case, thanks